# (1/1) NotFoundHttpException - Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found

Tags: laravel, routes

**Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.**
in RouteCollection.php line 179 I get an error.I did not understand problem. I am trying to update.

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request){
            $category = Category::findOrFail($request->id);
            $category->category_name        = $request->title;
            $category->category_keywords    = $request->keywords;
            $category->category_slug        = str_slug($request->title);

            if($request->hasFile('file_banner')){
                $file_bannerName    = str_slug($request->title).'.'.$request->file_banner->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $request->file_banner->move(public_path('img/category_img'), $file_bannerName);

                $category->category_files   = $file_bannerName;
            }
            $category->save();
            return redirect()->route('categories');
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('categories/update', 'Back\CategoryController@update')->name('category.update');
```

**Form**

```
<form action="POST" action="{{route('category.update')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{method_field('PUT')}}
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Başlık</label>
                                <input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="category_id">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Dış Banner</label> 
                                <input id="file_banner" type="file" class="form-control pt-3 pb-5" name="file_banner">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Anahtar Kelimeler</label>
                                <input id="keywords" type="text" class="form-control" name="keywords">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="submitEdit" class="btn btn-primary">Düzenle</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no value in

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="category_id">
```

therefore `$request->id` is empty

and `findOrFail` returns that the record was not found

Here's what I recommend

Change route

```
Route::post('categories/{id}/update', 'Back\CategoryController@update')->name('category.update');
```

Change form action

```
action="{{route('category.update', ['id' => $YourEditedCategoryId])}}"
```

Change controller

```
update(Request $request, Category $category){
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i forgot to add script

```
 <script>
    $(".edit-click").click(function(){
      id = $(this)[0].getAttribute('category-id');
      $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'{{route('categories.getData')}}',
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(data){
          console.log(data);
          $('#editModal').modal();
          $('#title').val(data.category_name);
          $('#keywords').val(data.category_keywords);
          $('#category_id').val(data.id);
        }
      })
    }); 
  </script>
```